# using subqueries in main query

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, mysql-error-1054

I have done like subquery like this but it was giving error

```
                    SELECT 
              sourceTable3.Total,
              (sourcetable3.datediff-1) as diff,
            ADDDATE(ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL FLOOR(diff) MONTH), INTERVAL DAY(NOW()) -            memberToMship_DueDay DAY) As expdate,
              ExpPayments, 
            MonthlyAmount, 
            SourceTable3.ExpPayments2, 
             FROM
             (
             SELECT 
                SourceTable2.Total,
             (SourceTable2.datdiff-1) as diff,
             SourceTable2.datdiff,                 
            ExpPayments, 
            MonthlyAmount, 
            SourceTable2.ExpPayments2, 
           member_Id 
          FROM 
          (
             SELECT 
              SourceTable.Total,
               ceil(SourceTable.ExpPayments-SourceTable.Total) AS datdiff,                 
              SourceTable.ExpPayments, 
                SourceTable.MonthlyAmount, 
            (SourceTable.Total/SourceTable.MonthlyAmount) as ExpPayments2, 
               SourceTable.member_Id 
          FROM 
           ( 
              SELECT                          TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,memberToMship_StartDate,memberToMship_EndDate)*      memberToMship_ChargePerPeriod As Total,     
DATEDIFF(GREATEST(NOW(),memberToMship_DueDay),memberToMship_StartDate)/30 AS ExpPayments,
30* memberToMship_ChargePerPeriod / DATEDIFF(memberToMship_EndDate,memberToMship_StartDate) AS MonthlyAmount, 
member_Id
            FROM 
            membertomships 
         ) as SourceTable
      ) as SourceTable2
  ) as sourceTable3
```

but it was giving error like this...

```
                         Error Code: 1054
                         Unknown column 'sourcetable3.datediff' in 'field list'
```

would any one pls help...

MODIFIED CODE :

modified 'e' and got the error like this

Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'memberTo_Mship_DueDay' in 'field list'

MODIFIED CODE :

this is my table structure

```
                                membership table
                              memberToMship_Id
                             memberToMship_StartDate
                             memberToMship_EndDate
                             memberToMship_DueDay
                             member_Id

                       I want finally these columns expdate , diff , ExpPayments, 
            MonthlyAmount, 





            MODIFIED CODE :




                SELECT 
           SourceTable3.Total,

          ADDDATE(ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL FLOOR(diff) MONTH), INTERVAL DAY(NOW()) -          memberToMship_DueDay DAY) As expdate,
          (Sourcetable3.datdiff-1) as diff,
         ExpPayments, 
            MonthlyAmount, 
          SourceTable3.ExpPayments2, 
           SourceTable3.member_Id
          FROM
          (
              SELECT 
            SourceTable2.Total,
             (SourceTable2.datdiff-1) as diff,
            SourceTable2.datdiff,                 
            ExpPayments, 
            MonthlyAmount, 
           SourceTable2.ExpPayments2, 
            member_Id 
                FROM 
                (
                        SELECT 
               SourceTable.Total,
                 ceil(SourceTable.ExpPayments-SourceTable.Total) AS datdiff,                 
                SourceTable.ExpPayments, 
               SourceTable.MonthlyAmount, 
              (SourceTable.Total/SourceTable.MonthlyAmount) as ExpPayments2, 
               SourceTable.member_Id 

               FROM 
               ( 
              SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,memberToMship_StartDate,memberToMship_EndDate)*      memberToMship_ChargePerPeriod As Total,     
                   DATEDIFF(GREATEST(NOW(),memberToMship_DueDay),memberToMship_StartDate)/30 AS ExpPayments,
           30* memberToMship_ChargePerPeriod /                      DATEDIFF(memberToMship_EndDate,memberToMship_StartDate) AS MonthlyAmount, 
member_Id
           FROM 
           membertomships 
          ) as SourceTable
        ) as SourceTable2
      ) as SourceTable3
```

and error

```
                        Error Code: 1054
                       Unknown column 'memberToMship_DueDay' in 'field list'
```

would any one pls help...

Comment: oh come on, check your tables

Comment: @wonk0 i have the  column memberTo_Mship_DueDay in memberTomship table   like  these fields ...memberToMship_EndDate,memberToMship_StartDate

Comment: @user682417 you are  stil in problem ,please give your table screenshot with the result you wanted .

Comment: @rahularyansharma pls see the question i have modified now...

Comment: @user682417: Why have you got 3 subselects going on now?? You only need 1..!! Did you look at my answer to your other question??

Comment: @stevie G oh i didnot sorry i will look at now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
      SourceTable2.Total,
      ADDDATE(ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL FLOOR(diff) MONTH), INTERVAL DAY(NOW()) -memberToMship_DueDay DAY) As expdate,
      datdiff, 
      diff,
      SourceTable2.ExpPayments, 
      SourceTable2.MonthlyAmount, 
      (SourceTable2.Total/SourceTable2.MonthlyAmount) as ExpPayments2, 
      SourceTable2.expdate,
      SourceTable2.member_Id 
FROM
(    
    SELECT 
      memberToMship_DueDay,
      SourceTable.Total,
      SourceTable.expdate
      ceil(SourceTable.ExpPayments-SourceTable.Total) AS datdiff, 
      ceil(SourceTable.ExpPayments-SourceTable.Total) -1 As diff,
      SourceTable.ExpPayments, 
      SourceTable.MonthlyAmount, 
      (SourceTable.Total/SourceTable.MonthlyAmount) as ExpPayments2, 
      SourceTable.expdate,
      SourceTable.member_Id 
    FROM 
    ( 
        SELECT 
          memberToMship_DueDay,
          TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,memberToMship_StartDate,memberToMship_EndDate)*memberToMship_ChargePerPeriod As Total, 
          DATEDIFF(GREATEST(NOW(),memberToMship_DueDay),memberToMship_StartDate)/30 AS ExpPayments,
          30* memberToMship_ChargePerPeriod /DATEDIFF(memberToMship_EndDate,memberToMship_StartDate) AS MonthlyAmount, 
          member_Id
      FROM membertomships 
    ) as SourceTable
) as SourceTable2
```

Comment: Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'diff' in 'field list'   this is the error i got ...

Answer (score 2):

I think that you need to remove the `e` from `datediff` so it becomes `sourcetable3.datdiff`.

Comment: ya i have removed that but it was giving error like this ...       Error Code: 1054.Unknown column 'memberToMship_DueDay' in 'field list'

Comment: @user682417: I would check your column spellings against the actual tables that you are referring too.

Comment: problem is at here    sourceTable3.Total,
 (sourcetable3.datdiff-1) as diff,
 ADDDATE(ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL FLOOR(diff) MONTH), INTERVAL DAY(NOW()) - memberToMship_DueDay DAY) As expdate,                                                     memberToMship_DueDay is not in field list

Comment: @user682417: Does `memberToMship_DueDay` exist in any of the tables?

Comment: @user682417: You use `memberToMship_DueDay` in the exterior SELECT list but I don't see it any interior SELECT list.

Comment: With interior, I meant subqueries.

Comment: Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ELECT 
 sourceTable3.Total, I got this error also...

Comment: @Neil Knight this is the  error i have got                         Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'memberToMship_DueDay' in 'field list'

Answer (score 1):

You have used different cases for `SourceTable3`:

`sourceTable3.Total,`
`(sourcetable3.datediff-1) as diff,`
`SourceTable3.ExpPayments2,`
`) as sourceTable3`

If you are on Linux, try changing them all to `SourceTable3`.  See [Identifier Case Sensitivity](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a typo in the line where that column is identified:

```
ceil(SourceTable.ExpPayments-SourceTable.Total) AS datdiff, 
                                          -----------^^-----
```

But you should enclose `datediff` in backquotes since it is a reserved MySQL keyword.

```
ceil(SourceTable.ExpPayments-SourceTable.Total) AS `datediff`,
```

Comment: thats also fine .. but now i got the different error   like this ...Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'memberToMship_DueDay' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0):

Well, which part of this error message is giving you trouble?
There is simply no column named datediff in sourcetable3, it is datdiff

Comment: Error Code: 1054 Unknown column 'memberTo_Mship_DueDay' in 'field list  this is the error

Comment: @user682417 Check the spelling against the actual table.  Also check that you are using the same case.  If you're on linux, column and table names are case sensitive.